# How to call multiple screens on one page in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have made a Home page in which there are three buttons in the header (like a tab navigator)  I want something like on clicking each button a screen appears beneath the header, as shown in the image below:
[image]

Here's what I have tried:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      initialstate: 0, //Setting initial state for screens
    };
  }
 render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.setState({ initialstate: 0})}>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/add.png')}
            resizeMode="contain"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.setState({ cardstate: 1})}>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/request.png')}
            resizeMode="contain"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.setState({ cardstate: 2})}>
      <Image source={require('../../assets/send.png')}
            resizeMode="contain"/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
 
      {this.state.initialstate == 0 ? ( <RequestComp/> ) : ( <TopUpComp/> )  } 
//Over Here when I use the Third Screen like " : <SendComp/> " it gives me JSX error says "EXPECTED }"
      </View>
```

Comment: you cannot use screen inside another screen for this u can use react-native-tab-view

Comment: what do you expect to have? Please give us a brief explanation.

Comment: @UA_ Just like the above screen I've created a screen now I have made three buttons on Pressing each button a new screen appears i.e onPress TopUp button TopUp screen appears on the same home page.. I actually dont want to do this with Tabs

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, what you need seems more like a popup that appears from the bottom of the screen. I use [react-native-popup-ui](https://github.com/RafaelAugustoS/react-native-popup-ui) `Toast` component to do that.

Something like:

```
import { Root, Toast } from 'popup-ui'
...
<Root>
   <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() =>
            Toast.show({
               title: 'User created',
               text: 'Your user was successfully created, use the app now.',
               color: '#2ecc71'
            })
         }
      >
         <Text>Call Toast</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</Root>
```

And the result is:

[image]

Note: I have android and the Taost is overlapped by android navigation bar but on iOS you should see all the `Toast` component

Answer (score -1):

you are using a ternary operator ( initial ? true : false ) which can work only for two components in your case.

Comment: do you think that this is an answer according to [answer]? Then please [edit] to make that more obvious. Otherwise, e.g. if you agree that this is more of a "Me too", please delete the post.